# What is the grammatical decomposition of "Se te ve tan diferente"?

Tags: gramática, se

What is the grammatical structure of ***Se te ve tan diferente*** answered in [How do you say "You look so different" in Spanish?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121108135053AAQdDFe)?

### se

Is this:

1. Passive form "**Se** + 3rd person present" ***se ve*** for a general statement like "se dice"? or
2. ***Se*** is just for emphasis like "se comió todos los platos por el mismo!"? or
3. Indirect object to mean to someone? or
4. Something else?

### te

Is this part of a reflexive verb ***verse***? If so, "me ve bien" means "I look well" like "va bien" = "I am good"?

But I believe **ver** is to look something which takes a direct object.

### Update

Having found [Usage of “ver(se)” for “to seem/look” (te ves, se te ve, te veo, etc.)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/933) and **se** is impersonal to make it general idea, but still not sure about **te ve** especially **te**. Is it basically a reflexive verb **verse** ?

Comment: "Te veo/noto diferente" I think if you use "se te ve" it's because more than one person feels the same way.

Comment: @PbxMan, thanks. It seems 'te ve' and 'te veo' are different according to http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/933/.

Comment: Some comments while someone has time to write about grammar. **Se ve** ="It looks", **Se te ve** ="You look...(to anyone)"  **Te ve** ="he/she sees you" or "he/she is looking at you" or "he/she can see you". **me ve bien** ="I look ok to him" or "he can see me well". **va bien** ="it goes well" (not "I am good" that would be "estoy/voy bien") and finally **ver** is _to look_ but it is also _to see_

Answer (score 1):

**Se** is a *clitic* personal pronoun used in impersonal sentences in Spanish. It also can be used in some kind of passive sentences, called "*pasivas reflejas*", but it's not the case. 
The way to distinguish both of them is kind of tricky, but we know that "*Se te ve tan diferente*" is an impersonal sentence because we can say the same with "*Se ve tan diferente a ti*" (although it doesn't sound very well). And as the RAE (Royal Spanish Academy) states [HERE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables):
"If the nominal element refers to a person and it's preceded by the 'a' preposition, the impersonal contruction must be used; so, the verb will be in singular form even the nominal element is in plural form.

**Te** references "you" in that phrase, so it's what we call a "*objeto directo de persona*" in Spanish (something like "*personal direct object*").

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does "(Tu vestiendote en la ropa) te ve bonita a ti" make sense? If "Te" is direct object, I suppose it is part of a reflexive verb, and "You wearing the cloth" makes an effect of "looking good" against "her = tu", like "me robó el coche"?

Comment: Sorry to disagree. **Se te ve tan diferente** means "I look at you and I see you so different to your usual looks" and **Se ve tan diferente a ti** means "someone else looks very different than you" and both sentences sound perfectly fine but meaning different things. (note: the first sentence could also mean "That thing you are wearing looks very different in you than it does on someone else" ) (note 2: I guess many of my English prepositions are wrong. I'm not sure if I should use "to" instead of "than". I hope you could understand what I mean)